# Tell lighttpd used protocol (HTTPS) when Nginx reverse proxy is in front

Tags: https, lighttpd, web.py, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Nginx reverse proxy redirecting to a lighttpd server in the same machine. This reverse proxy works on HTTPS so I want to tell to lighttpd that HTTPS is being used as protocol instead of HTTP. Here is my Nginx confuguration.

```
server {

  server_name mydomain.com;
  merge_slashes off;
  rewrite ^(.*?)//+(.*?)$ $1/$2 permanent;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/;
      proxy_set_header Host       $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # SSL settings
}

server {
    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
}
```

The lighttpd server is running a python application that uses **web.py** module but the returned value by `web.ctx.protocol` still is **HTTP** when it should be **HTTPS**. It looks like lighttpd ignores the **X-Forwarded-Proto** header sent by Nginx.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any additional configuration to be done?
Thanks.

Comment: On a side-note, you should host your python application on localhost on http, and let nginx do SSL handshake/termination.

Comment: But doesn't your `proxy_pass` set protocol to `http`? What happens if you set `proxy_pass https://localhost:8088/`? (Your lighttpd server is running https, right?)

Comment: No, the lighttpd server is not running https as I think it is not necessary for that purpose (that's why I am trying to use those headers to avoid setting https on lighttpd). If I set https in the proxy_pass it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure lighttpd to trust headers from upstream.  Use mod_extforward in lighttpd.  See https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModExtForward

Better than your many headers above, both nginx and lighttpd (via mod_extforward) support RFC 7239 Forwarded header.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Use of the "Forwarded" header should be preferred.